# changing apache root directory prevents me from accessing .git/config

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, apache-http-server, git

I copied over a php folder from computer to another and hooked it up to apache.. however apache would return `page forbidden`.. after doing some research it turned out it was a matter of giving apache access to the folder.. so this is what i did:

```
sudo chown -R _www /website/directory
```

however after doing that, running my git alias commands such as `git la` returns this error:

```
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
```

if I run whoami I get `admin`.. so I decided to add admin to the _www group like so:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a admin -t user _www
```

running

```
dseditgroup -o checkmember -m admin _www
```

returns

```
yes admin is a member of _www
```

however running git la still returns the same error above.. what do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change owner of `/website/directory/.git` to your user:

```
$ chown -R admin /website/directory/.git
```

Comment: ok maybe i should have asked the question a different way: how do i give apache access to my project root directory.. without taking away any of my admin user rights? b/c right now i can't even save the file in phpstorm or anything! if i run ls -l I get `drwxrwxrwx  19 admin  admin   646B Apr 22 17:39 lesson-plan-dev` every other file in that directory has something like this `drwxrwxrwx   6 admin  staff   204B Mar 31 10:37 libraries`.. ideas?

Comment: please update main question if you want to ask something else completely.

Comment: ok i'll mark your question as answered.. and ask another question

Comment: asked [here](http://superuser.com/questions/744941/how-do-i-give-apache-access-to-my-project-root-directory-without-taking-away-any)